# System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path '/SHP/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js' was not found or does not implement IController

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Some time ago I upgraded a legacy application to use JQuery-1.6.2.
Thanks to Elmah I occasionally get emails with the above exception, but users do not notice anything.
It should be an easy bug to fix, just do a global search for 1.4.4 and remove the reference.
Except when I do that search there is no line of code that refers to that.
So I am not sure what I need to do to track down the problem. The Exception information does not give a line number.
This is what the email says;

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path '/SHP/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js' was not found or does not implement IController.     at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)     at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)     at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)     at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)     at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)     at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Could be someone with a cached version of your HTML?

Comment: Good point. I restarted the server in IIS and I would hope that would have eliminated that possiblity but I could be wrong. I am surprised I am still getting these messages 2 months later. I wonder what more I can do about this?

Comment: Restarting your server wont flush the users cache. Only correct cache response headers will do that. But it could be another thing causing that as well.